# Mirror windows on X (Linux)

Tags: linux, windows, thumbnails, dwm, screen-recording

I am required to write a very efficient application that will mirror the contents of an arbitrary external application multiple times (a lot of times) onto an area of my window, for Linux. On Windows, the way I used to do it was with the help of `DwmRegisterThumbnail` which would tell the compositor (Desktop Window Manager) that I want it to draw the thumbnail of that foreign window, which it anyway generates, onto a rectangle in my own window, when it composes the desktop image to be displayed to the user on the monitor. This is, I think, one of the lowest overhead ways to achieve my goal, on Windows. The goal is to have very minimal impact on the CPU, as the app will run on a pretty constrained machine. I never tested it against GDI or DirectX methods of copying the screen data, but I do not believe it is faster. Or maybe I am wrong, do correct me if so, please. Is there any other method faster on Windows? The limitations of this method include not being able to touch the actual image data, so no drawing on top of it for example, which is fine for my goal.

Now, my question is, what would be the best approach to achieve this on Linux? I have full liberty of choosing an appropiate X server, display manager if needed and also can write whatever software just to make it as low overhead as it is on Windows. Is there a similar API to the one on Windows for some Linux compositor, like Mutter or KWin, that works well? Or should I hook into X and copy image data from it? Would that eat a lot of CPU?

What's your experience and opinion? How should I take on this?

Thank you very much.